# Jarring refresh rate on LaTeX display

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, math-se

Whenever I enter LaTeX formatted questions and answers on sites such as Math.SE and CSTheory.SE, the region that dynamically displays the formatted text below the text-box. This is a wonderful feature. However, it updates with every keystroke. The time necessary to render/format the LaTeX is slow enough that the text is first displayed unformatted, then within roughly half a second, the formatted text is displayed.

Since the size of the unformatted and formatted text are significantly different, this leads to a very jarring, disruptive appearance. Every keystroke, the text changes back and forth between the two wildly different formats.

A couple of possible solutions:

- Optimal: Only display the formatted text if no new text was received in the last ~2 seconds.
- Simpler: Add a toggle checkbox to temporarily turn off LaTeX display.

With the bounty running out after a week, is it correct to assume this is not easily fixable?

Comment: Syntax highlighting is also applied with a delay (5 seconds of inactivity) so your 'optimal' option should be feasible.

Comment: Solution #3 upgrade your computer, the preview is rendered in browser.